# Stuck in proving an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have this little problem.
I have this function
$$
   f(x, y, z)=\ln x+\ln y+3 \ln z=\ln xyz^3
   $$
I have found the extrema in the sphere  $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=5 r^{2}$ with $x>0, y>0, z>0$ 
Which is
$$    f(r,r,\sqrt{3}r)=\ln (rr3\sqrt{3}r^{3})=\ln 3\sqrt{3}r^{5}$$
Well, the problem  is:

Use previous result to prove that:
If $a, b$ and $c$ are real positive numbers
$$
    \boxed{a b c^{3} \leq 27\left(\frac{a+b+c}{5}\right)^{5} .}
    $$

I thought  I could use the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means
$$ \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\ldots x_n}\leq\frac{{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}}{n} $$

So I did, using it with $a$, $b$, and changing $c^3$ to  $c\cdot c\cdot c$

$$
   \sqrt[5]{abc^3}\leq \frac{{a + b + 3c}}{5} \to    abc^3\leq  \left(\dfrac{a + b + 3c}{5} \right)^5
   $$
Next step seems to separate $\frac{a+b+3c}{5}$ into $\frac{a+b+c}{5}+\frac{2c}{5}$ but seems to get things worse.

Is there any different or simpler approach to prove it?

Comment: Unfortunately, your AGM inequality isn't enough to show the first inequality, because $27[(a+b+c)/5]^5 < [(a+b+3c)/5]^5$ if $c > a+b$.

Comment: You can try to do this: $\frac{abc}{27}=ab(\frac{c}{3})^3\leq (\frac{a+b+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{c}{3}}{5})^5=(\frac{a+b+c}{5})^5$(by AM-GM), and change this function into yours.

Comment: @ItozDarbien excellent, except for the third power, which dropped out on the left side.

Comment: Actually:) I'm sorry about that, it should be $\frac{abc^3}{27}$ on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a rather nice one:

As we had in previous result, we can assure

$$  \ln xyz^{3}\leq \ln\left (\sqrt{27}\,r^{5}\right )$$
Using the sphere equation
$$  \ln xyz^{3}\leq \ln\left (\sqrt{27}\,r^{5}\right )\Rightarrow  \ln xyz^{3}\leq\ln \left [\sqrt{27}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{5}}\right)^{5}\right ]
  $$
$$  \ln xyz^{3}\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\ln \left (27\left (\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{5}\right )^{5}\right )
$$
$$
  2\ln xyz^{3}\leq\ln \left (27\left (\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{5}\right )^{5}\right )$$$$
\ln x^{2}y^{2}z^{6}\leq \ln \left (27\left (\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{5}\right )^{5}\right )$$$$
x^{2}y^{2}z^{6}\leq  27\left (\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{5}\right )^{5}
$$
Changing:
$$  \begin{aligned}
   a&=x^{2}\\
   b&=y^{2}\\
   c&=z^{2}
  \end{aligned}
$$
We have
$$  abc^{3}\leq  27\left (\dfrac{a+b+c}{5}\right )^{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Do as the problem says and use the previous result. Let $x^2=\sqrt{a}$, etc. Then we get

$$\log\sqrt{abc^3} = \frac{1}{2}\log (abc^3) \leq \log(3\sqrt{3}r^5)$$

$$\log (abc^3) \leq 2\log(3\sqrt{3}r^5) = \log(27r^{10}) = \log(27(r^2)^5)$$

Exponentiate both side then we have

$$abc^3 \leq 27(r^2)^5 = 27\left(\frac{a+b+c}{5}\right)^5$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $$abc^3\leq27\left(\frac{a+b+c}{5}\right)^5$$ for positive variables we can prove also by smoothing.

Let $a+b=constant$.

Thus, $ab$ gets a maximal value for $a=b$.

Let $c=3k^5a$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that $$k^{15}\leq\left(\frac{2+3k^5}{5}\right)^5$$
or
$$3k^5+2\geq5k^3,$$ which is true by AM-GM.